# How to make FlexLayout not waste space between items?

Tags: position, alignment, controls, maui

I have a MAUI.NET project and I am listing some items inside a FlexLayout which works nice. I have just one requirement.

[image]

Basically I want to move the first item in the second (red rectangle) row upper (so it stays at blue rectangle position), so it doesn't waste a space.

It seems that the tallest item in the row define the space for the whole raw. I would like to omit this behaviour.

Here is my code (I have tried to set it up with all available parameters):

```
<ScrollView Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalOptions="Fill" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10">
    <FlexLayout Direction="Row" Wrap="Wrap" JustifyContent="Start" AlignContent="SpaceAround" AlignItems="Start"  AlignSelf="Start" VerticalOptions="Fill"/>
</ScrollView>
```

The additional difficulty is that I generate items in runtime and their have dynamic height - after clicking SPECIAL MODE CONFIGURE the grey area is unfolded.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the child item is arranged in rows and the size of child elements are different. So the space is not wasted but in the row.

I think you may define an inner FlexLayout, just like the following code (an example):

```
<ScrollView>
     <FlexLayout  Direction="Row" Wrap="NoWrap"  >

        <FlexLayout Direction="Column" Wrap="NoWrap"  FlexLayout.Grow="1">
            <Border WidthRequest="200"  HeightRequest="200" BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
            <Border WidthRequest="200"  HeightRequest="200" BackgroundColor="Yellow"  />
         </FlexLayout>
         <Border   WidthRequest="200" 
                HeightRequest="300" BackgroundColor="Green"  />
    </FlexLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The inner FlexLayout's direction is Column up to down which may arrange the two smaller child to be aligned as one column. The outer FlexLayout's direction is row left to right which defines the position relationship for bigger childs and two smaller childs.

By the way, I think using Grid can easily achieve this layout, why using a FlexLayout instead? With [Rows and Columnns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid?view=net-maui-7.0#rows-and-columns) definitions, can more easily and accurately design the layout.

For more info, you could refer to [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid?view=net-maui-7.0).

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The reason for using FlexLayout is foremost that while the size of window is changed the FlexLayout arranges the items dynamically in a nice way. Moreover I am creating the items with the ViewModel-First architecture. In runtime my app reads different xml requirements and builds views based on the ViewModels that I parse from xml. Because od that the proposed solutions could be harder to implement. Note that after each click the item resize itself. So I would need to recalculate grid or double FlexLayout over and over. I hoped there is a way to make it by properties.

Comment: Because I don't know the exact item control so i just use border as an example. May I ask the result if you use my answer?

Comment: Actually I can't implement it because of the reason I have mentioned - I am building ViewModels and let it render the views itself. It already is a complex and render quite heavy (performance) Doing it this way would require even more complex. My questions was regarding these options of FlexLayout. I understand it is not possible now. Need to play with these code one time, but there are big priorities on this project. So I have no results to share. Anyway I admire the help of MS. I assume you are from the company. I like MAUI.NET and I hope that you may polish it so it would be perfect. THANKS

Comment: Thanks for your response. You could also raise an issue on [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).